# How can I query a User from my Angular front-end service?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, mongoose

**QUESTION:**

I am trying to query the currently logged in user in my front-end angular 2 service with:

```
 UserModel.findById(userID, function (err, user) {
```

It seems this behaviour is possible from the browser, how can I query the user from my service ?

---

**ERROR:**

After running `npm run build` with webpack and then `npm start`:

```
user.js?b9cb:19 Uncaught TypeError: mongoose.model is not a function
```

Which brought me to search online for the meaning of the error and effectively found that mongoose does not support queries from the client ?

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4779

---

**CODE:**

**models/user**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    polls: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll'}],
    votes: [{
      poll: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll'},
      choice: {type: Number},
    }],
});

schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

**client.service**

```
var UserModel = require('../../../models/user');

voted(poll: Poll, userID: string, choice: number) {
          UserModel.findById(userID, function (err, user) {
            var result = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < user.votes.length; i ++) {
              if (user.votes[i].poll == poll.pollId) {
                result = "disabled";
                if (user.votes[i].choice == choice) {
                  result =  "selected";
                }
              }
            }
            return result;
          })
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to run your Angular app in some type of environment like electron or is this running in the browser? If the latter, then I suggest you actually read the "issue" you reference, since this is just not going to work in a browser. If you are trying to ask "How do I access MongoDB from the browser" then don't. Instead type that phrase into your fav search engine and start reading the results.

Comment: Why the downvote, please explain. I am willing to modify my question if necessary :)

Comment: @NeilLunn I know. That's why I am asking a question here :D I would like to know how I can query my user from my service since it's not possible from the browser with my current implementation.

Comment: For the record that's not my downvote. But I think what I said there is the explanation why someone did downvote. I.e There is bucketloads on information out there on the "how do I use from browser" question, since you are not the first to ask.

Comment: @NeilLunn I should have made it clearer that I understand I cannot query MongoDB from the browser, I am just asking what I can do to query my  user from within my service.

Comment: you should create an endpoint in your service and let it respond with the results so that the query happens in the server but is asked via front-end client

Comment: @mnemosdev Ok, I see how do that except for one detail: I am new to angular2 and don't know how to make a request to my endpoint from the service. What is the syntax ? Woud you write an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the http module for Angular2 to make requests. This one is a GET request, but I'm sure you can make all the others request if you wish so.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'http-app',
  templateUrl: 'your-template.html'
})
class YourComponent {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('your-endpoint')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(json => this.json = json);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using it in a service, not a component :D

Comment: you can still use the same http.get(endpoint) approach, even in a service